# PyQt application on retina displays

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, anaconda

I have PyQt4 (and Qt4) installed through Anaconda, but applications that use it look terrible on Apple retina displays. I understand that if you've installed Qt without a package manager, you can edit the `Info.plist` to include keys and values that will force the application to be rendered as retina-capable. However, this does not seem possible when Qt is installed through Anaconda.

Is there a way for a PyQt application to still "trigger" this retina rendering when the installation of PyQt/Qt is through a package manager?

(The application supports both PyQt5 and PyQt4, however, when installed through Anaconda, it uses PyQt4 because Anaconda official supports only PyQt4 as a default package.)

Comment: The only way I know about is to create a standalone executable (e.g. using PyInstaller) and changing the `.plist` there.